# Video events inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video, html5-audio

Can we fire HTML5 audio/video events when bootstrap modal is shown?

Example:

```
$(".abc").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
         $("video")[0].oncanplay = function(){
            alert("canplay");
         };
    });
```

Comment: You want to show the video in that modal itself??

Answer (score 0):

this worked for myself...

in js file

```
$(function() {
    $('#videoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var src = $('#videowrapper').attr('data-iframe-src');
        $('#videowrapper').attr('src', src)
    });
    $('#videoModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $('#videowrapper').attr('src', '')
    })
});
```

in modal content area

```
<div class='embed-container'>
                        <iframe allowfullscreen data-iframe-src='[YOUTUBE URL]?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0' frameborder='0' id="videowrapper" name="videowrapper" src=""></iframe>
                    </div>
```